# Sound notification in Terminal

Tags: sound, command-line, gnome-terminal, notification, teminal-bell

I've never used this feature, but I think that in KDE Konsole Terminal you can configure sound notifications. This is the screenshot:

[image]

I find this useful when you execute a command client that wait for an event (like ping) or when finish a long script, you work in other task and hear your bell/alarm configured.

It is possible to achieve this with Gnome Terminal? Can I install other terminal over Gnome? Help me find some hack.

Comment: You can just use Konsole in Ubuntu.. though to theme it you'll need qt4 settings too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something called *terminal bell* in gnome-terminal. But it doesn't notify if commands are finished or waiting for user input.

[image: Screenshot]